# CSVHelper dual licence

Tags: csvhelper

I want to add CSVHelper as a nugget package in commercial software.
CSVHelper has dual license MS-PL and Apache-2.0.
On a project site it's written that we can choose between this two licenses.
I don't understand how I can choose.
MS-PL is a copy-left license.
How this works with dual licences works?
Do we by using this software accept MS-PL or not?

Answer (score 1):

There were a lot of corporations that accepted only MS-PL, but others that didn't know what MS-PL was but accepted Apache-2.0. CsvHelper has a dual license to allow for usage in more businesses. It doesn't matter to me which you choose. It only matters to the company you work for. If this is software you're writing and not under some other company, pick one and follow it's rules. I personally don't care how you use the software. The only thing I don't want people doing is selling the source or binaries by themselves, since people should get it for free. If you feel either of those licenses don't cover what you need to do, submit an issue on github and we can discuss changes to make it work for you.